# does not contain defination for 'ReturnsAsync' and best extension method overload

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Not able to call this function CallComplianceStarter ...

getting error cs1929 Isetup<IworkFlowService, Task>'does not contain defination for 'ReturnsAsync'and best extension method overload

```
 public async Task<object> Get_Compliance_QueryParameter_ReturnsOkStatusCode()
        {
            //Arrange


           var mockServiceResult = new { TriggerFlow = "Test" };

            _mockService.Setup(x => x.CallComplianceStarter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MessageHeader>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(mockServiceResult);



            var workFlowsController = new WorkFlowsController(_mockController.Object, _mockService.Object);
            workFlowsController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
            workFlowsController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            //Act
            var result = await workFlowsController.Get("P");
            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(((ObjectResult)result).StatusCode, (int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return result;
        }

public async Task<WorkFlowsResponse> CallComplianceStarter(string flowName, MessageHeader messageHeader)
{
            
  // Imeplementation         
 return new WorkFlowsResponse { TriggerFlow = flowName };
           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option A

you should change the `CallComplianceStarter` signature to be synchronous.

While the _mockService really has a method with:

```
Task<WorkFlowsResponse> CallComplianceStarter(string flowName, MessageHeader messageHeader)
```

The Test should be

```
public WorkFlowsResponse CallComplianceStarter(string flowName, MessageHeader messageHeader)
{                
    // Imeplementation         
    return new WorkFlowsResponse { TriggerFlow = flowName };               
}
```

---

If you will pay attention to the `ReturnsAsync` signature you will see that it has an overload that accept only on argument: `TResult value`.

```
public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult>(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> mock, TResult value) where TMock : class;
```

### Option B

Not sure why in the first place you need this `CallComplianceStarter` in your test? are you just copying it from production? I believe you will need only a specific return value like `new WorkFlowsResponse { TriggerFlow = "MyFlowName" };`.

and use it with:

```
var expected = new WorkFlowsResponse { TriggerFlow = "MyFlowName" };
_mockService.Setup(x => x.CallComplianceStarter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MessageHeader>()))
.ReturnsAsync(expected);
```

Comment: Hi Shahar even this one is not throwing exception ,  var mockServiceResult = new WorkFlowsResponse { TriggerFlow = "Test" };

            _mockService.Setup(x => x.CallComplianceStarter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MessageHeader>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(mockServiceResult);